# What is inhibiting polystyrene's ability to dissolve in traditional solvents like ethanol or acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, plastics

My friend and I have been struggling with this problem for a couple days. Because polystyrene has a similar structure to many plastics, we assumed that it would dissolve in acetone. However, after running several tests, we found that polystyrene would not dissolve in a measurable quantity even if we let it sit in acetone for a significant amount of time.

Here is the plastic we are attempting to dissolve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF16p.jpg

And here is a plastic more easily dissolved:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo2BT.jpg

We understand that most molecular-bonded plastics dissolve via van der Waals dispersion forces, so why isn't polystyrene dissolving? My theory is that the benzene ring is interfering with the dissolving process -- that only half the compound of polystyrene is interacting with the acetone and thus it does not dissolve like a polyethylene (which obviously has twice as much surface area to dissolve).

Comment: Are you using bulk polystyrene or expanded polystyrene? expanded polystyrene clearly dissolves very quickly in acetone but bulk polystyrene might take much longer simply because it has a much smaller surface area for the acetone to infiltrate.

Comment: We are using extruded polystyrene -- so styrofoam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polystyrene *is* soluble in acetone, MEK and other ketones, but [solubility and *the speed* with which it dissolves depends, in part, on the molecular mass of the polymer](https://books.google.com/books?id=vzM-tMSwRZoC&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=polystyrene%20solubility%20acetone%20methyl%20ethyl%20ketone&source=bl&ots=y2tfb7f3oo&sig=SU-iPUtjwa6CFRKfk0RnZKwPXTc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihi6eusqDMAhWEbD4KHdKdANsQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=polystyrene%20solubility%20acetone%20methyl%20ethyl%20ketone&f=false).

If the solvent diffuses very slowly into the polystyrene, only the surface will appear to be affected. Applying a bit of energy with heat or mechanical crushing of the plastic greatly speeds the action of the solvent.

For more technical information, see [Solubility Parameters: Theory and Application](http://cool.conservation-us.org/coolaic/sg/bpg/annual/v03/bp03-04.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered monoterpenes as polystyrene solvents? Have a look at:

Shikata et al. (2011) Dissolution of polystyrene into cyclic monoterpenes present in tree essential oils. Journal of Material Cycles and Waste Management 13(2):127-130

Gutiérrez et al. (2012) Recycling of extruded polystyrene wastes by dissolution and supercritical CO2 technology. Journal of Material Cycles and Waste Management 14(4):308-316.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.